# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on dataadapter.Fill(databtable);

Tags: c#

I have this program which I am working into. Then when I started to debug it, it seems perfectly running smooth. But then it just stops and then a note popped up

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Incorrect syntax near '`'.'

Here is my code.

```
public void searchData(string valueToSearch)
{
     string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(`lastname`, `middle`, `firstname`, `username`) like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

and the message popped up on `sda.Fill(dt);` and I don't really know what part is the problem since it doesn't show up on the error list.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the value of `valueToSearch`? Note that this code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)!

Comment: And are back-ticks (like you use in `CONCAT(``lastname``...`) valid quotation marks in SQL?

Comment: Specify the RDBMS you're using, connections are for SQL server but your column name escape notation seems like MySQL

Comment: @user6144226 the RDBMS *has* been specified: `SqlClient` refers specifically to SQL Server

Comment: As a side note, I should point out that using data-adapters, data-tables, etc - is not really the main direction of code these days. It'll work, but please don't think that this is the norm. It *does still happen*, but... there are much better ways of working with data.

Comment: @MarcGravell  It seems if the T-SQL stored proc raises an error with severity less than 11, the `SqlClient.SqlException` is not percolated up through the `SqlDataAdapter` class. The adapter's `Update(table)` method doesn't catch an error with severity < 11.  What pattern do you recommend as a replacement for the SqlDataAdapter with its registered select, insert, update, and delete commands and `RowStateFilter`?

Comment: @Tim to observe messages with a severity below 11, you need to [subscribe to the `InfoMessage` event on the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage); as for adapters: honestly, just don't; for complicated data orchestration, proper ORMs like EF or LLBLGenPro are the way to go; for "just run this query and get me the data" / "just execute this command" purposes: Dapper; adapters and `DataTable` are redundant legacy concepts IMO

Comment: @MarcGravell   Thanks for the InfoMessage link.  Legacy app written almost 20 years ago and uses SqlDataAdapter throughout.

Comment: @Tim OK; then it is going to use outdated approaches; fixing that is a large amount of work - whether it is worth it is contextual and subjective

Answer (score 4):

The params in the concat function are surrounded by quotes, which doesnt make sense. Those have to be the column names.

Change your query object to :

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(lastname, middle, firstname, username) like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
```

Comment: it worked. but what makes var different from string? sorry i'm just a grade 11 student so...

Comment: The `var` bit isn't important. The rest of the changes are the important bit. _If `var` is confusing, just change it to `string`._

Comment: The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement. - MSDN.  Look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables
If you find it confusing, change it to string.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your SQL; the *immediate* one is that you're using the wrong variant of escaping. SQL is "more what you call *guidelines* than actual rules", and different vendors use different rules. You're using *backtick* escaping of the form:

```
`identifier`
```

You also mention `SqlClient` in the question, which tells us that you're using SQL Server. SQL Server uses TSQL syntax, where `[identifier]` is the correct escape syntax - and it is optional, so unless your column/table names are reserved keywords you can just use the name directly:

```
 WHERE CONCAT(lastname, middle, firstname, username)
```

---

The second and IMO much more serious problem is: SQL injection. You should **never ever** concatenate user input into a query. That's how a huge number of data breaches and outages happen - it is a **huge** security hole, and the sooner you learn not to do that: the better. Instead, use *parameters*:

```
 string query = "... like @searchVal";
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchVal", "%" + valueToSearch + "%");
 // ...
```

This *completely protects you* from SQL injection (unless you've done something silly inside the SQL, such as `EXEC`-ing it), *and* (in the case of numbers / dates / etc) solves a wide range of "culture" issues (such as whether "123,456" is "one hundred and twenty three **thousand** four hundred and fifty six", or whether it is "one hundred and twenty three **point** four five six").