# Can SQL Server return an informational message to .NET System.Data.SqlClient program in contexts that do not involve any error

Tags: t-sql, system.data.sqlclient

Is it possible with a .NET client program,  communicating with back-end SQL Server using the System.Data.SqlClient library, for the server to send an informational message to the client program **in contexts that do not involve any error** and for the client program to obtain the message that was sent?

```
  create proc NewFoo            
    @value text,
    @userid text
    as
    begin
     insert foo
     (name, createdby) values (@value, @userid);

     declare @recordcount int
     select @recordcount = count(*) from foo where createdby= @userid;

     if @recordcount = 100
         begin
           -- let user know they've created their 100th record. Woo-hoo!!
         end
   end
```

Here is an additional pseudo-code example, closer to the actual use case; note the differing severity:

```
 if @value > @maxallowed
   begin
      if @userlevel = 'manager' 
           raiserror('Exceeded max. Intentional?',10,1)
      else
           raiserror('Exceeds max. Your edit was not saved',11,1)
   end
```

P.S. Without using an OUT parameter or RETURN value parameter in the client-side command object.

P.P.S.  I am using the SqlDataAdapter.Update method and some of the code uses a DataReader on the SqlCommand object.

Comment: Depends on how you define "an error". The `RAISERROR` function can be used to return informational messages to the client - anything with a severity less than 11 isn't treated by SQL Server as an error in terms of `TRY`/`CATCH` or aborting anything.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  But will an SQL Server error severity less than 11 percolate up to the client? How/where does the client get the message?

Comment: However the message is generated, if it is coming from the SQL Server without being directly requested, your app would have to be coded to be listening/checking for that message in one way or another. Is there a reason you don't want to check your results with an additional query on success (or something like that)?

Comment: @DavidThompson :   In essence, it's a feature that lets managers override a business rule. A user with managerial privileges will receive only a warning (severity 10) that a value was invalid  (e.g. amount paid > max payment allowed) but the insert/update will succeed; normal users will have the statement rejected (severity 11).  The warning for managers is to make sure their violation of the business rule was not accidental.

Comment: @MarcGravell gave me a lead in a comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359528/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-on-dataadapter-filldatabtable?noredirect=1#comment120530265_49359528 but in my brief bit of testing it seems using the InfoMessage event `Connection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true` disables the exception catching for severity >= 11.

Comment: Further on that, when `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true`,  a `Reader` on a `SqlCommand` object (`reader= cmd.ExecuteReader()`) does not work when an error is raised in the SP, even if the error severity < 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PRINT in your stored procedure, and to capture it in the code by subscribing to the InfoMessage event in the SqlConnection object.

In your sql just put:

```sql
    PRINT 'Exceeded max. Intentional'
```

and in your code grab it like this:

```cs
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string msg = null;
        connection.InfoMessage += (sender, e) => { msg = e.Message; };
        // execute the procedure
        // check msg
    }
```

Comment: I had tunnel-vision, focusing on T-SQL RAISERROR.  Thanks!